# No overload for method 'RenderPartial' takes 3 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

This is driving me crazy, i am getting:

`No overload for method 'RenderPartial' takes 3 arguments`

a compresed version of my `_layout`:

```
    <head>
    @{
      var footer = new footer(User);
      var pageTitle = ViewData["Title"].ToString();
    }
    </head>
    <body>
        @{ 
            Html.RenderPartial(
                  "_footer",
                   footer,
                   new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) { { "pageTitle", pageTitle } }
            );
        }
    </body>
```

in my shared `_layout`, i am trying to pass a model to the partial view and a string which is provided by `ViewData` not sure what is going on.

i am setting title from the page `_mypage.cshtml` that uses that layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "My Title";
}
<h1>Hello there</h1>
```

`_footer` is a partial view where i am using the `footer` object and also calling other partial view where i need the title.

Comment: Where and how have you defined `pageTitle`?

Comment: i added that part just now

Comment: Nut you still have not shown where you are declaring `pageTitle` in `{ "pageTitle", pageTitle }` - the code you have shown generates _The name 'pageTitle' does not exist in the current context_, not the error you are claiming

Comment: You have also not indicated what `footer` is

Comment: It is impossible to get the **No overload for method 'RenderPartial' takes 3 arguments** error with the code you shared.

Comment: i was checking and there is no `System.Web.Mvc` only `Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC ver1.1` feel like that is root of my issues

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using ViewBag.

*MyController.cs:*

```
// set the title on a ViewBag inside your action
ViewBag.pageTitle = "My Title";
```

*_layout.cshtml:*

```
// call your partial view passing the model
@Html.Partial("footer", footer);
```

*_footer.cshtml:*

```
<!-- use the ViewBag data with @ -->
<h1>@ViewBag.pageTitle</h1>
```

Comment: but i am setting the title from the page that uses the layout like this: 
`@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "My title";
}`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @DavidLee user ViewBag.Title instead of  ViewData["Title"], is more easy, you dont need to pass by reference, just use ViewBag.Title across the views